# how do i store these values into just one Session PHP

Tags: php, session

I have this variable that contains multiple values and I want to save all the values into a `$_SESSION['gamecode']`. It displays only the last value.

```
$var=explode("|",$key);
    $gamecode=trim($var[0]);
session_start();
$gc[]= trim($var[0]);
$_SESSION['gamecode'][]=$gc;
var_dump($_SESSION['gamecode']);
```

**EDITED**

```
foreach($_POST['gm'] as $key => $answer){
    if($answer != ''){
    $var=explode("|",$key);
    $gamecode=trim($var[0]);
$_SESSION['gamecode'][]=$gc;
    var_dump($_SESSION['gamecode']);
```

**EDIT 2**

```
foreach($_POST['gm'] as $key => $answer){
        if($answer != ''){
        $var=explode("|",$key);
        $gamecode=trim($var[0]);
  }
    $_SESSION['gamecode'][]=$gc;
        var_dump($_SESSION['gamecode']);
```

Comment: no close on `if` or `foreach`, please add those

Comment: and now `$gc` is not defined. and either the `foreach` or the `if`  is not closed and its not possible to tell which. please spend some time writing a coherent question before posting - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. by starting the Session in the foreach loop and calling it outside the loop. it works fine. Thanks

```
foreach($_POST['gm'] as $key => $answer){
        if($answer != ''){
        $var=explode("|",$key);
        $gamecode=trim($var[0]);
$gc[]= trim($var[0]);
$_SESSION['gamecode']=$gc;
  }



var_dump($_SESSION['gamecode']);
```

Comment: glad you found an answer - but seriously no one could of worked this out based on what you asked - please keep that in mind next time - and mark this as answered

Comment: thanks. I wouldn't have figured it out if you and john conde didn't comment. can marked as answered in two days. thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you want all the values

```
$var=explode("|",$key);
$_SESSION['gamecode']=$var;
```

or just

```
$_SESSION['gamecode']=explode("|",$key);
```

currently your just storing the first one.

`$var[0]` is the first array element after the explode

Comment: I suspect they need a loop to get all of the values they are looking for

Comment: its possible, but based on that question this is my best guess - if OP edits, ill update

Comment: Its the first one i need. and it contains some values from a loop.

Comment: `$var[0]` is the first one not the last one, so there must be more code your not showing us.

Comment: need to see an example of `$_POST['gm']`, exploding the `$key`? are you sure it should not be the `$answer`?

Comment: @Dagon they've a similar question posted yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/q/30823171/ with an accepted answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup sigh, sometimes i regret bothering

Comment: @Dagon Glad I didn't retract my closing for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-:) added mine, this has changed so much it will be about the price of bananas in china soon

Comment: @Dagon OP posted their own answer. The other one looks like yours too. Now to go and check if my banana stocks haven't suffered by all this.

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to have $_SESSION['gamecode'] be an array of piped values? Or $_SESSION['gamecode'] to be an array in and of itself?

It's not completely clear what you're trying to do here.

It looks like you've got piped values in $key, that you're making into array $var, and extracting the first value to $gamecode.

There's a lot of redundancy here, and you're not being explicit about what you want.

If you're trying to have $_SESSION['gamecode'] be an array with multiple values, you'd want to do something like

```
session_start();
$var=explode("|",$key);
$_SESSION['gamecode'] = $var;

print_r($_SESSION['gamecode']);
```

Else if you want it to be a string of multiple values, it might be more fruitful to make $key a JSON string, no?

Not really enough details for me to give you a succinct answer.

Comment: this looks a lot like Dagon's answer

Comment: i just made an edit on the codes. Please check. i exploded the $key from a loop